# Reducing sequential correlations in Metropolis Algorithm

Tags: markov-chains, correlation, monte-carlo

In our last lab, we use MCMC method to simulate a walker walking in the phase space. Using the Metropolis method, a walker at its currect position will sample another point inside a cube (centered at the current position) with side length  $\eta$ with equal probabilities. Then he accepts or rejects this attempted move by calculating the energy difference.

The instructor told us we should choose $\eta$ so that about 60% of the attempted move will be accepted.

He also stated that to reduce sequential correlation, we should add the sum not at every step, but after every $n$ steps (say $10$ steps).

My question is, why don't we just increase the step-size $\eta$, which will also reduce sequential correlation. The instructor's answer is that in that case most of the attempted move will be rejected and this reduces the efficiency. However, by sampling $10$ points and using only $1$ of them, we have also lost an efficiency of $90$%. I think that's no difference than making $\eta$ larger.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually why, but one concern is at the level of computation. If you can draw 10 samples and choose 1 the extremely vast majority of the time, then branch prediction will usually be successful which gives quite significant performance improvement. This could very well be enough to mitigate the additional cost associated to drawing more samples in the first place.

Comment: The other question is what exactly you're trying to extract from your MCMC simulation. If it is just the stationary distribution, which is often the case for the Metropolis dynamics (which are usually "synthetic" dynamics, meaning that they don't really mean anything except inasmuch as they produce the desired stationary distribution) then your instructor is 100% correct, and the objective is basically to minimize the total number of trials required to achieve a given total distance (or time, in the continuous time context).